# Mysql Delete old, except latest 2 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write below query in simplest and fastest way? because i have to run this query every hour to delete oldest data on above 15000 rows.

I have a database and need to delete all oldest rows if exist except latest 2 rows.

```
| ID | RID  | group  | data |
| 1  |  22  |  5m    | abc  |
| 2  |  22  |  5m    | abc  |
| 3  |  22  |  5m    | abc  |

| 4  |  22  |  7m    | abc  |
| 5  |  22  |  7m    | abc  |
| 6  |  22  |  7m    | abc  |

| 7  |  23  |  5m    | abc  |
| 8  |  23  |  5m    | abc  |
| 9  |  23  |  5m    | abc  |


(delete only 3rd oldest row and more if exist)
DELETE FROM table WHERE RID = 22 AND group = "5m" ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2,100; // Delete ID 1
DELETE FROM table WHERE RID = 22 AND group = "7m" ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2,100; // DELETE ID 4
DELETE FROM table WHERE RID = 23 AND group = "5m" ORDER BY ID LIMIT 2,100; // DELETE ID 7
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: above mention mysql quries, i need to run these quires 1000 times with different RID, and GRP,  i want to make it 1 query,

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? If you are, you can use window functions to find the latest 2 rows in each group, and then exclude them with a join.

Comment: If appropriate, it's often quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep. The drop the old table. Then rename and re-index the new table. That said, consider whether you really have to run this repeatedly, or whether you could restructure your schema and inserts to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to optimize these queries, then create an index on the table on `(rid, group, id desc)`.

Note that `group` is a really, really bad name for a column, because it is a reserved SQL keyword.

Assuming that `id` is unique, you can phrase all your queries as a single `delete`:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by rid, group order by id desc) as seqnum
          from t
         ) tt
         on t.id = tt.id
    where seqnum > 2;
```

I would note that deleting basically all the rows in a table is an expensive operation.  It is usually faster to re-create the table with the handful of rows that you really want.

Comment: group name just on stackoverflow to explain .

Comment: it does not work, it return error at  over (partition by

Comment: @YpagesOnine . . . This requires MySQL 8+.